# facebook javascript sdk login popup not opening up

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, http-status-code-302

I am trying to implement facebook login on website. Following is my code:

```
    $('#facebook_login').live('click',function(){
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

      if (response.status === 'connected') {

          var data = {facebook: true, accessToken: response.authResponse.accessToken }
          $.ajax({
                url: '/registerajax',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
          });
      }else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            alert('The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.');
        } else {
            alert('The person is not logged into Facebook, so we\'re not sure if they are logged into this app or not.');
        }   
 },{scope:'publish_actions'});
});
```

As per the chrome console, I am getting 302 from facebook. I googled it but could not find any relevant post.
[image: google chrome console]

Comment: There is nothing wrong for 302. May I see your demo page to help further?

Comment: I am sorry, its not live currently. I am working on my local. There is no error in console so I though 302 may be problem

Comment: Could you please share your whole code for facebook login in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Code mentioned at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1 works fine, don't know why but not the current one. I think, it will serve the purpose

Comment: However, you are using custom button, not using fb login. If you provide entire code, I can help